# How to Add a "Target" to a pod file? (such as HockeyApp)

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I'm reading [React Native Cookbook](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/react-native-cookbook/9781786462558/) by Crysfel Villa, Stan Bershadskiy

I'm at a chapter on using hockeyapp and not sure how to setup the podfile. These are the directions:

> **How to do it...** 
>   First we need to install the react-native-hockeyapp
>   module in our application. Open the Terminal, go to your application's
>   root project directory and enter the following command: $ npm install
>   react-native-hockeyapp --save Go into your ios/ directory and
>   initialize your Podfile: `$ pod init` Open your Podfile and add pod
>   "HockeySDK" to your target. Back in the Terminal, install the Podfile:
>   `$ pod install`

I am not 100% sure about **"add pod HockeySDK to your target"**

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp

  target 'MyApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'MyApp-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp-tvOS

  target 'MyApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Any idea on how to modify the pod file correctly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include `HockeySDK` module in `MyApp` target (which is the app that you are builidng) you just need to add `pod 'HockeySDK'` line like this:

```
target 'MyApp' do
   (...)
   pod 'HokeySDK'
   (...)
end
```

Then after running `pod install` open `.xcworkspace` file instead of `.xcproj`. You can find more information in official [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) guide.